# How to increase value by 1 each time a JButton has been clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I've just learnt about `ActionListener` and my task is to create a simple application using a `JButton` associated with the `JLabel` which displays an `int` to be increased by the value of 1 each time it has been clicked. Here's my coding:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonPanel2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

JButton button2;
JLabel secondLabel;

int i = 1;
int total = 0;

ButtonPanel2()
{
    button2 = new JButton("Push");
    add(button2);

    button2.addActionListener(this);

    secondLabel = new JLabel("Button pushes: " + total);
    add(secondLabel);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    total += i;
}
}
```

And the driver class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestButtonPanel2 {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    JFrame buttonFrame2 = new JFrame("Button Panel 2");

    ButtonPanel2 panel2 = new ButtonPanel2();

    buttonFrame2.add(panel2);
    buttonFrame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buttonFrame2.setSize(400 , 400);
    buttonFrame2.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ActionListener`, update the GUI like that:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    total += i;
    secondLabel.setText("Button pushes: " + total);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-set the text on the JLabel inside of the actionPerformed method. Even though you pass in the `total` variable into the label, all the label gets is the current value it holds. The label's text won't magically change, you have to do this by calling `setText(...)` each time you want it to change.

Comment: This is a shame really, we have `ListModel`s, `ButtonModel`s, `TableModel`s etc, but no `LabelModel`. A lot of the web frameworks would in fact allow the label to change magically (Albeit they also decide on what's redrawn as well). Another point the OP seems to be missing is that not only the label constructs an immutable `String` in `setText`, he is also passing a primitive `int`, meaning the `Label` would never have any clue what happens to the value later, even if there was a proper model.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks so much for your explanation mate I get what my mistake is now. Cheers! :D

Comment: @Ordous lol it's too complex for my level right now to understand mate. ><

Comment: @Ordous: it would be easy for someone to construct a "LabelModel" object and then tie it to to the JLabel via a listener structure of some kind such as a SwingPropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListener.